# Appending Form Data To Previous Post

Tags: php, forms

This form submits only to itself and does not create any database entries. Instead, the values are formatted in a particular way, then presented on the page. It works well but I need to be able to keep the previous on-screen text while putting the next form submission below it and I'm not sure how to do that.

This is what does the form processing:

```
// NOTE: this form does not make any database entries
if (isset($_POST)) :
    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) unset($_POST['insert']);
    $Values = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $value) :
        if (!is_numeric($value) && !Contains("$",$value) && $value !== "TRUE" && $value !== "FALSE") $value = "\"$value\"";
        $Values[] = trim($value);
    endforeach;
    $output = implode(",",$Values);
endif;
```

. . . then on the page, currently it is simply using **echo $output;** which, of course, gets overwritten with each form submission. The output looks something like this:

```
"Field Name","FieldName",4,0,0,TRUE,"this is a test",$sqlLookup,FALSE,$siteDB
```

I thought perhaps that it could be done using a buffer but I'm not sure how to implement it as this code below obviously makes no sense even to me.

```
if (isset($_POST) && isset($output)) :
    //echo "$output<p>\n\n";
    ob_start();
    echo $output;
    $fieldvalues = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
endif;
```

Comment: try to use sessions or cookies

Comment: You can use use javascript for form submission instead.

Comment: As a back-end and database programmer, I would have no idea how to use Javascript but I do use sessions all the time. Not sure, though, how to do that either without the value getting overwritten just as it is now. Some ideas expressed as code would be most helpful.

Comment: Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_database.asp A little you can understand that you'll be on same page and can send request to another file using javascript. No page reload and you can show content into div after getting response. If something breaks I'll help you out.

Comment: Although I've virtually never used it, I had thought of Ajax but there are no database calls being used (all the examples seem to need one) and the form itself is being generated dynamically using an array of values. I was hoping for a basic PHP solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using Ajax, JavaScript or anything other than PHP, I was able to get the needed results using sessions as was suggested. Now I just need to come up with a way to clear the values for the next set of submissions which shouldn't be too difficult.

```
// BEGIN SESSION TO STORE OUTPUT
if (!isset($_SESSION['output']))  $_SESSION['output'] = array();

// RETRIEVE POST VALUES TO ARRAY
if (isset($_POST)) :
    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) unset($_POST['insert']);
    $Values = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $value) :
        if (!is_numeric($value) && !Contains("$",$value) && $value !== "TRUE" && $value !== "FALSE") $value = "\"$value\"";
        $Values[] = trim($value);
    endforeach;
    $output = implode(",",$Values);
endif;

// APPEND ARRAY WITH NEW POST    
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_SESSION['output'])) :
    array_push($_SESSION['output'],$output);
endif;

// FORMAT VALUES FOR DISPLAY        
if (isset($_SESSION['output'])) :
    echo "\n<p><h4>Field Values</h4>\n\n";
    foreach ($_SESSION['output'] as $value) echo "$value<br>\n";
endif;
```